# Customize order by for MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to do something like this: `select * from table order by id asc` with the exception that if the id is 5 (for example) make it be top, basically 5 then all other IDs ordered asc.

How can I do this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN id = 5 THEN -1 ELSE id END AS ordering 
FROM table 
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Comment: Your welcome! I prefer this type of solution because it is a single query, so with a proper index, it can perform quite well

Answer (score 4):

You can also use function `FIELD()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5) DESC
       , id ASC
```

Especially useful if you want to have first the rows with say, id = 5, 23, 17, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 17, 23, 5) DESC
       , id ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION` as initally suggested by me, with a sorting on both columns as suggested by @Mike in the comments.

```
(SELECT *, 1 single_id FROM table_name WHERE id = 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *, 2 all_ids FROM table_name WHERE id <> 5)
ORDER BY single_id, id
```

Or better off with an `IF` statement, to avoid the overhead of two sorts:

```
  SELECT *, IF(id = 5, -1, id) ordering 
    FROM table_name
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Comment: have you tested this?  i don't think the sql spec specifies that this will return each unioned set in its own order in the sequence that you unioned them in...

Comment: @Karolis: Yes, forgot the parentheses, they will do the trick. :)

Comment: @Randy: I just tested it, it returns them just like that.

Comment: @Adrian: Are you happy with an `IF` statement?

Comment: Removed the downvote because of the `IF`, but will not upvote because using UNION and hoping that it will maintain order is still wrong

Comment: @Shef: Just add a sort column.  See the end of the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) docs.

Comment: @Mike: I could do that, but it wouldn't use indexes. Thus, the best option remains an `IF` statement or `SWITCH` as the OP chose.

Comment: @Shef: Good point.  It will still use an index for the `WHERE` and the inner `ORDER BY`, but not for the final UNION order.  But then the IF statement suffers from the same problem - the `ordering` column is not indexed either.

Comment: @Mike: I added that syntax, just in case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Shef: ...but then the IF statement suffers from the same problem - the `ordering` column is not indexed either.

Comment: @Mike: ;) That's why I added the syntax! However, there will still be an overhead with the `UNION`, because two sorts should be done.

Comment: @Shef let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1881/discussion-between-mike-and-shef)

Comment: If you want to use UNION, you don't need the inner `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks, forgot to get rid of that.

Comment: Small corrections: `UNION ALL`, added `,2` and `WHERE id <> 5` in the 2nd subquery.

Comment: @ypercube: I believe, there is no need to add `id <> 5`, because `UNION` will select `DISTINCT` values without the `ALL` flag.

Comment: No, because you'll have a row with `id=5, single_id=1` and one with a `id=5, single_id=2`. Plus you can use `UNION ALL` which doesn't lose any time selecting distinct rows.

Comment: @ypercube: I tested, and it doesn't seem to make a difference. However, even if we come up with miracles for `UNION` it is a horrible solution. The speed differences were so dramatic compared to the one with the `IF` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id=7 DESC, id ASC
```

Since this doesn't use indexes, I don't recommend using it on large tables.